# How to count number from highest to lowest number column in sql and php?

Tags: php, sql

Example column in sql:

```
id|viewed
1|1000
35|500
47|1200
79|700
84|300
```

I use "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY viewed desc", the result I get:

```
47|1200
1|1000
79|700
35|500
84|300
```

But I want to add "number order" by Top id ( like ranking ) in PHP, example text:

- ID 47 is 1
- ID 1 is 2
- ID 79 is 3
- ID 35 is 4
- ID 84 is 5

So what I need to add these top with PHP guys, I think will use $i++ to count number or something like this in php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from the sql query itself :

May be you should try this:

```
set @row_num = 0;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS number,id,viewed FROM `table` ORDER BY viewed desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Increment a variable during the loop that prints the results.

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "ID {$row['id']} is $i<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY viewed desc");
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC);

count = count($rows);
echo '<ul>';
for ($x = 0; $x < count; $x++) {
  echo '<li>ID ' + $rows[$x]['id'] + ' is ' + $x + '.</li>'
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much !